# Show numbers in Arabic, and show only decimal numbers if needed in Excel

Tags: excel, decimal, number-formatting, arabic, arabic-support

I have numbers, some of them are integer and some are fractional.
What I want to achieve is:

1. Type and show numbers in Arabic format: [image]
2. And when typing integers, show them as integers. And when typing decimal, show them without any rounding.

So I used this custom format cell expression:

```
[$-2000000]###0.#######
```

But this shows a comma when I insert an integer number: [image: integer number with comma]

So, what I should I do to type numbers in Arabic in Excel? And to show decimals or comma when necessary?

**Note:** You can suggest me other solution, like a universal solution to type Arabic numbers in Excel. But this Excel file will be shared with many people. I want to make sure that the numbers shows in Arabic for all users and show decimal and comma if needed.

I put a number in C14 cell and tried to make a conditional format and used this function `=MOD($C14,1) = 0` and formatted it as `[$-,200]###0.#######` but didn't work.

Comment: This site for programming/coding stuff , it is better to ask your question on the sister site https://superuser.com/

Comment: I always thought that the numbers 0123456789 are called Arabic numbers? :-)

Comment: @Dominique There are conflicts regarding this matter, a team sees that 0123456789 are Arabic numbers and some people sees them as English numbers. But here we consider it English

Comment: ??? **English???** The 0123456789 numbering system is invented in India and has been brought from India over Arabia into the European region, largely before England and its affiliates had the power they have now. What place on Earth is that ignorant to call 0123456789 English numbers?